# How would I make this code into a fractal?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I have a beginning star. Now, how would I make this into a fractal?

```
import turtle

turing = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(5):
    turing.forward(110)
    turing.left(216)
```

Answer (score 2):

A fractal is something that repeats with some variation.  So put your star-loop code into a loop and repeat it several times.  Change something after doing each star-loop.  You could change where the turtle is, or what angle it is pointing at, or how long the side of the next star will be, or any or all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Following @mgkrebbs general philosophy, with a simple fractal that deflects a line, we can make all the lines of the deflection smaller duplicates of the fractal.  Your star is tricky to work with but since it has verticies, we can recursively put smaller stars at each vertex:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def star(turtle, length, depth):
    turtle.left(90)
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(length)
        heading = turtle.heading()
        if depth > 1:
            star(turtle, length / 2, depth - 1)
        turtle.setheading(heading)
        turtle.left(216)

turing = Turtle()
turing.speed("fastest")

star(turing, 180, 3)

turing.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

As the depth increases, you can see the stars start to overlap -- making the image larger by increasing `length`, or making the recursions a smaller fraction of the `length`, may help.

**OUTPUT**

[image]